# Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am try to do my first project in angular.
I have success fully printed my first Hello world program.

my index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.ts

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

app.component.ts file

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  Hello {{details.firstName}}
`
})
export class AppComponent { 
    public details = {firstName : "gopi",lastName : "mohan",phoneNumber :"789456123",e-mail :"sadf@asljfdk.com"};
    
}
```

I have followed the 5mins quick start.

> I am trying to print the first name of the object in my view part but i am getting the below error
>
> Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: In Javascript, the variable `e-mail` is interpreted into `< e minus mail >` if you want to use dashes in variable names you need to put quotes around them like this `"e-mail"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing details as following-

```
public details = {"firstName" : "gopi","lastName" : "mohan","phoneNumber" :"789456123","e-mail" :"sadf@asljfdk.com"};
```

See if this helps.